# Changing value works with eager loading but not lazing loading in linq and ef

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

### this is not '*a problem*' question , but '*why this happens*' question.

```
var chapters = story.Chapters.Select(
                    ch => new ChapterDisplayViewModel { 
                                   Id = ch.Id,
                                   Number = ch.Number});
```

first i want to get some data. story is an entity type of type `Story` and it has One To Many relation with `Chapter` i want to change some data in the chapters collection that i got so i write some condition if so change the value

```
if(chapters.Any(c => c.Number == chapterNum))
   chapters.Where(c => c.Number == chapterNum).Single().IsSelected = true;
```

and then i send the data to the view but the problem is :

nothing is changed due to lazy loading , the change that i made wasn't triggerd even after sending the data to the view , **Why ? i made an assigment statment and shouldn't passing the data to the view trigger it ?**

the solution was of course using ToList to execute the query immediately

```
var chapters = story.Chapters.Select(
                    ch => new ChapterDisplayViewModel { 
                                   Id = ch.Id,
                                   Number = ch.Number}).ToList();
```

i just want an explanation to the behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you say that you have a lazily loaded collection `Chapters` on your `Story` class I assume that `Chapters` is actually a collection of dynamic proxy objects. If you look what happens in the database with a profiler you will see that this line ...

```
var chapters = story.Chapters.Select(
               ch => new ChapterDisplayViewModel { 
                               Id = ch.Id,
                               Number = ch.Number});
```

... executes a query in the database which queries all `Chapter` objects (the projection into `ChapterDisplayViewModel` doesn't happen in the database). And that's the only database query. The following ...

```
if (chapters.Any(c => c.Number == chapterNum))
    chapters.Where(c => c.Number == chapterNum).Single().IsSelected = true;
```

... is executed in memory on the already lazily loaded collection of `Chapters`. The projection happens at this point.

But this means that the `Single` operator materializes a `ChapterDisplayViewModel` object, it means: There happens a `new ChapterDisplayViewModel` somewhere internally. Simple check for this:

```
var viewModel1 = chapters.Where(c => c.Number == chapterNum).Single();
var viewModel2 = chapters.Where(c => c.Number == chapterNum).Single();

bool sameObjects = object.ReferenceEquals(viewModel1, viewModel2);
```

`sameObjects` is `false` which means `Single` doesn't simply return references to ViewModel objects which are already in memory but creates new instances of them.

When you apply `ToList` in the first query the ViewModels are materialized at once into a in-memory collection of ViewModels and `Single` will simply return a reference to the matching, but already existing object. `sameObjects` will be `true`.

So, without `ToList` you are setting the `IsSelected` property on a just materialized object which you don't reference anymore and therefore disappears in garbage collection immediately. With `ToList` you are setting the property on the unique object inside of the in-memory collection. When you use this collection in your view the flag is still there.

Comment: In other words it has nothing to do with lazy or eager loading. Lazy loading happens anyway. It is just very nice example of deferred execution of linq queries. Great explanation.